# Crontab enviromental variables

Tags: environment-variables, cron

Struggling a bit on this...

I'm using crontab for a lot of todo list management:

Here's a snippet of my crontab...

```
$TASK=/home/pgrads/joseph/emailAnalysis/single
0,30 * * * * ~/emailAnalysis/python/script.py
15,45 * * * * $TASK/task.sh "foo"
10,40 * * * * /home/pgrads/joseph/emailAnalysis/single/task.sh "bar"
```

My problem is that the 'foo' task is not triggering - I get the error "/bin/sh: /task.sh: No such file or directory".

A few googles haven't got me very far - mainly they just give me variations on the man page... :s  any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$` from your first line:

```
TASK=/home/pgrads/joseph/emailAnalysis/single
```